# Can SRP be implemented using libsodium

Tags: key-exchange

I am using libsodium for cryptography and I want to use [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) for key exchange. The wikipedia page lists a python example, but I am not sure if and how I could convert this to libsodium function calls.

Is it possible or would I need to implement some operations myself?

Comment: It doesn't look like SRP is natively supported by libsodium, and as it is its own protocol, I would tend to down that it could be implemented entirely using libsodium function calls. You may want to look at https://pythonhosted.org/srp/srp.html